# I have a class that needs to access 3 other classes for data

Tags: java

I am trying to make a text editor rpg and I wanted to have a player class, a playerStats class, a race class, and a classType class. I’m not sure what the best way to have the player class incorporate the 3 other classes. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could do this?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and get your first badge. Create a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for clarity and add  code here

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate the player class and the other 3 classes, then supplement them into the player class. It will look something like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Player player = new Player();
    PlayerStats stats = new PlayerStats();
    player.setStats(stats);

    ...
}
```